# Jasmine SpyOn on function calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

Hello I got a question regarding mocking JS code with Jasmine.

Imagine having the following situation:

```
function Test(){
    var a = 5;
    var b = 3;
    Test2(a,b);
}
function Test2(a,b){
    var result = a + b;
    console.log("result of function Test2: ", result);
}
```

I want to mock my Test2 function call with Jasmine. I tried the following thing:

```
describe("1# Test Mocking", function () {                                   
    it("test: Mocking Example", function () {                                                           
        var myMock = new Test();                        
        spyOn(myMock, "Test2").and.returnValue(10,10);              
        expect(Test2.result).toEqual(20);       
    });         
});
```

But Jasmine keeps saying: `Error: Test2() method does not exist`

Does anyone knows why this is and how I could solve this?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @AndreasNiedermair. I changed the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make a lot of sense I'm afraid:

- you're telling Jasmine to spy on a method of `myMock` called `Test2`, yet it doesn't have such a method (as Jasmine is telling you); `Test2` is just a regular function;
- even if it did had a method called `Test2`, you're spying on it *after* `new Test()`, at which point the original `Test2` would already have been called and the spy would be declared too late;
- the original `Test2` doesn't return a value, yet you are telling the spy that it should return `10, 10` (it seems to me that you want to *call* it with those two values, not have it *return* them);
- `Test2` doesn't have any side-effects (like returning a value or setting an instance variable or something) apart from creating a local variable (`result`) and logging it, which makes it pretty untestable;

I think you need to go back to the drawing board to formulate what exactly it is you want the class to do. To help you on your way, here's a possible implementation, including a test to see a) if `Test2` gets called with the proper arguments and b) if its return value gets stored properly (again, I don't know what you want the class to do, so I'm just providing some examples):

```
function Test() {
  var a = 5;
  var b = 3;
  this.result = this.Test2(a, b);
}

Test.prototype.Test2 = function(a, b) {
  var result = a + b;
  return result;
}

describe("1# Test Mocking", function () {
  it("test: Mocking Example", function () {
    spyOn(Test.prototype, 'Test2').and.returnValue(20);
    var myMock = new Test();
    expect(myMock.Test2.calls.argsFor(0)).toEqual([ 5, 3 ]);
    expect(myMock.result).toEqual(20);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really a good explanation. I got a bit lost by understanding how spies work in Jasmine. Your example and your explanation really helps me.